# How to convert List<string> to xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I need to convert a List of String to XML format, I am using the below code to convert the List to XML

```
XElement xmlElements = new XElement("DocumentElement", _UserIDs.Select(i => new XElement("BadgeNo", i)));
```

Current Result:

```
<DocumentElement>
 <BadgeNo>IMS001</BadgeNo>
 <BadgeNo>IMS002</BadgeNo>
 <BadgeNo>IMS003</BadgeNo>
 <BadgeNo>IMS022</BadgeNo>
 <BadgeNo>WAN35166</BadgeNo>
</DocumentElement>
```

But I need something more, I need to add an extra node in like this. How can I achieve the below output

Expected Result:

```
<DocumentElement>
 <GroupInput>
   <BadgeNo>IMS001</BadgeNo>
 </GroupInput>
 <GroupInput>
   <BadgeNo>IMS002</BadgeNo>
 </GroupInput>
 <GroupInput>
   <BadgeNo>IMS003</BadgeNo>
 </GroupInput>
 <GroupInput>
    <BadgeNo>IMS022</BadgeNo>
 </GroupInput>
 <GroupInput>
   <BadgeNo>WAN35166</BadgeNo>
 </GroupInput>
</DocumentElement>
```

Thanks in Advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select new "GroupInput" element while passing new "BadgeNo" element as the parameter :

```
XElement xmlElements = new XElement("DocumentElement", 
                            _UserIDs.Select(i => 
                                        new XElement("GroupInput", 
                                                new XElement("BadgeNo", i))
                            )
                       );
```